# Ansible Skipping Docker Build

Tags: docker, ansible, devops

Trying to get Ansible set up to learn about it, so could be a very simple mistake but I can't find the answer to it anywhere. When I try to run ansible-playbook it's just simply skipping the job with the following output:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts simple-devops-image.yml --check

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host 127.0.0.1 is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change this. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more
information.
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [build docker image using war file] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [127.0.0.1]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

My .yml playbook file:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: build docker image using war file
    command: docker build -t simple-devops-image .
    args:
      chdir: /usr/local/src
```

My hosts file:

```
[localhost]
127.0.0.1  ansible_connection=local
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command` module is skipped when executing with `check` mode. Remove `—check` from `ansible-playbook` command to build docker image.

Here is a [note from the doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#notes):

> Check mode is supported when passing creates or removes. If running in check mode and either of these are specified, the module will check for the existence of the file and report the correct changed status. If these are not supplied, the task will be skipped.